# use flag to 'continue' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger submit_form function only after all fields are filled. Now the submit form will got triggered.

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $('body input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      alert('Please fill in ' + $(this).attr('placeholder'));
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    }
  })

  submit_form();
});

function submit_form() {
  alert('proceed to sumbit form.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type="" placeholder="name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="hp">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: where is your form?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @rahul submit form is the function

Comment: @hindmost requirmennt : submit form when every form is filled, otherwise alert which fill is not filled.

Comment: What is exactly wrong with your code?

Comment: try my answers @NingSia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var flag = 1;
    $('body input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '')
        {
            alert('Please fill in ' + $(this).attr('placeholder'));
            $(this).focus();
            flag = 0;
            return false;
        }
  else
  {
    flag = 1;
  }
    })
    if(flag)
    {
        submit_form();
    }
});

function submit_form() {
  alert('proceed to sumbit form.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type="" placeholder="name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="hp">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, according to your code your submit functions always calls so i have added a flag for it please check....

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var flag = 1;
    $('body input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '')
        {
            alert('Please fill in ' + $(this).attr('placeholder'));
            $(this).focus();
            flag = 0;
            return false;
        }
    })
    if(flag)
    {
        submit_form();
    }
});
```

Comment: i updated his answer .he missing that small else condition  if ($(this).val() == '')
        {
            alert('Please fill in ' + $(this).attr('placeholder'));
            $(this).focus();
            flag = 0;
            return false;
        }
      else
     {
         flag=1;
      }     now its work perfect

Comment: your fiddle is wrong  look where i have set the "var flag = 1;"

Comment: @jothi there is not need of else condition

Comment: @NingSia have you checked it?

Comment: submit the form without value means flag set falg=0 then you enter value submit while also flag=0  then how form submitted ? so need else condition @rahul     working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jhwoh6yk/

Comment: try with your code, you will come to know what is wrong. both cases will work but else is no use there as i have defined the default flag value to 1

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to prevent submitting your form when one input field is empty.

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  this.canSend = true;
  $('body input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      this.canSend = false;
      alert('Please fill in ' + $(this).attr('placeholder'));
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    }
  })
  if (this.canSend) {
    submit_form();
  }
});

function submit_form() {
  alert('proceed to sumbit form.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="" placeholder="name">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="hp">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="email">
<br>
<br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

A refactored version also available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/j74u8wvL/

Answer (score 0):

Remove all JavaScript.

```
<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="hp" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="email" placeholder="email" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```